# VBA - Inserting formula into cell with Sumproduct

Tags: excel, vba

i hope that someone out there can help me on what i am doing wrong here. I am not super strong at VBA so the solution might be very simple, but i have just not been able to crack what i am doing wrong to transfer the range into Sumproduct.

A bit of background. range_new_table1 and range_new_table2 is a 10 by 6 table that i need to get the sumproduct of.

I don't need the result of the sumproduct, as that works (see line commented out and in bold)
I need it to be a formula, as the range is input fields and will be filled out later.

I tryed the following the last line returns =SUMPRODUCT('Theme Capacity'!range_final) in excel

```
    Sheets("Theme capacity").Range("Initiative_table_AddRow").End(xlUp).Select
    range_new_table1 = (ActiveCell.Offset(-10, 1).Address)
    range_new_table2 = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Address)

'Selecting Source Worksheet
Worksheets("Theme Tracking").Activate
    Sheets("Theme tracking").Range("Area_initiative_CapNeed").End(xlDown).Select
    range_formula = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Address)
    range_final = "'Theme Capacity'!" & range_new_table1 & ":" & range_new_table2
    MsgBox range_final
    **'Range(range_formula2) = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Range(range_final))**
    Range(range_formula2).Formula = "=SumProduct(range_final)"
```

Comment: try `"=SumProduct(" & range_final & ")"` -> you have to pass the value of your variable to the string.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It worked! 
I thought i actually tried that, but can see in my code from earlier tried, that i forgot that second & after my variable.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ike i got the code working using the following:

```
Range(range_formula2).Formula = "=SumProduct(" & range_final & ")"
```